# clang: error: no such file or directory: Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

hello folks got stuck in this error.

> **clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/astutesol/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Cricket_App-fhjgxyyxntnfoudotqonxggicgck/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCordova.a'**

any suggestions please

Comment: Are you using Cordova? If so, please add it to the tags.

Answer (score 1):

1. Close Xcode and clear Derived data from (/Users/astutesol/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData)
2. Now, open project clean->build. And try.